# Rails 4: How do I extract a select_all query from controller to Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a complicated Class.connection.select_all query I would like to extract from controller#index to a class method in the corresponding model. (The query is complicated because it has multiple LEFT OUTER joins on sub-queried data and other tables).

The `Class.connection.select_all` query works fine when it's in the controller, but the following class method returns only an empty hash.

```
 def self.long_query_name(some_param)
  connection.select_all("Lots of SQL goes here")
end
```

Query result (simplified for readability):

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::OID::Float:0x00000004d3e588,                                                
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::OID::Date:0x00000004d3dfc0},                                                         
 @columns=                                                                                                                                                         
  ["expected/correct column headers"],                                                                                                                                             
 @hash_rows=nil,                                                                                                                                                   
 @rows=[]>
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: What is the reason to have plain SQL in your app? Does it make sense to rewrite the query with Rails methods?

Comment: I would blame params. Are they really the same in both cases?
By the way, if the query is really complicated you can consider using a view (if you use postgresql database, that is).

Comment: "lots of SQL goes here" = SELECT several fields FROM (sub-query on my_table) LEFT OUTER JOIN (second sub-query on my_table) LEFT OUTER JOIN (third sub-query on my_table) WHERE some_column = some_param. All related by unique alphanumeric identifier (similar to product SKU).

Comment: @spickermann I would love to use Rails methods to build the query but the sub-querying combined with joining on the alphanumeric unique identifier (versus default primary/foreign key) makes this seem impossible...? Perhaps I need to redesign my schema to utilize the unique alphanumeric identifier instead of the (unused/useless-to-me) class_id...? I don't feel I am utilizing my relations to full capacity since I am not leveraging my unique identifier. Guidance here would be great.

Comment: @AndriusBuivydas Sorry, can you please clarify? Are 'they' really the same? Apologies, what do you mean by 'they'? Also, what do you mean by using a view for the query? Doesn't this violate "separation of concerns?" I am using PostgreSQL. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: I ment that `some_param` value could be different when you call that method from the controller and from the model.
Postgresql views doesn't violate "separation of concerns" - you can think of a db view as a [virtual table](http://alexpotrykus.com/blog/2013/04/10/postgres-views-in-rails/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `find_by_sql` should to the job:

```
def self.long_query_name(some_param)
  find_by_sql("Lots of SQL goes here")
end
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. For my understanding: why does .connection.select_all("SQL query") **not** work?

Comment: Adding that the API docs suggest find_by_sql as "a last resort" [link](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_by_sql/class) because the hard SQL query is database-dependent (MySQL different from ORACLE, etc.). I am not suggesting @spickermann 's suggestion is bad in any way, but am asking that if anyone knows a better way to write my query (described in comments above) that I would be very grateful. I will post another question.